# Is there an scp variant of mv command?

Tags: linux, scp, mv

I am writing a script that will move files from a local system to a remote system.  It must do so through an encrypted channel like ssh.  What is the best way to do this?  I can perform this in two steps like:

```
scp *.jpg user@ip:
rm *.jpg
```

But, that is not an atomic process (like mv is for a local filesystem).  If the copy fails I will no longer have the local copies either.  How can I script this to make sure the local files only get removed if the copy succeeds?

Comment: Off topic since not programming related.

Comment: then where should I post this question?

Comment: Also not a bash question. Neither scp nor mv are part of bash; they work exactly the same way with any other shell.

Comment: @ChrisMaes: Superuser.com, most likely.

Comment: "just like the mv is cp and then remove source" That's not quite correct. Respectively, it is only correct for distinct file systems. If you move inside one file system, the file is kept where it is and just the name is changed.

Comment: Go to unixstackexchange.com, askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `rsync` with `--remove-source-files`:

```
rsync -avz --remove-source-files /local/dir/*.jpg user@ip:/remote/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution,  for launch in one time

```
scp /path/src/*.jpg user@host:/path/dst/ && rm /path/src/*.jpg
```

Comment: Note when doing this that if new files are created in `/path/src/` _during_ the scp copy command they will be deleted and not copied.

Comment: Very risky, if scp command terminate for any reason, files car be deleted without having being copied.