# Unix Is there a way to send a file between 2 servers with single command?

Tags: unix, ssh, scp

I want to send files to the remote server using ssh protocol, so i need something between `mv` and `scp`.

I want files only sent, not copied. So I'm asking if there's option to do it without `rm` after `scp`.

Note: It will be included inside a script which will then be executed by a cron, so no options such as manually via WinSCP etc.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an scp variant of mv command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534309/is-there-an-scp-variant-of-mv-command)

Comment: @Jin-ohKang yes, i've browsed throught a lot of pages and didn't find it, it's funny how similiar the question is. Thanks a lot.